# Let's get critical: Jul 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [French Language & Usage Stack Exchange](http://french.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://french.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [French equivalent of "or else"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6450/french-equivalent-of-or-else)

  **Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 11, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Future in the past](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6598/future-in-the-past)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 16, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Doit-on employer le pluriel après « genre », « sorte » et « type » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6638/doit-on-employer-le-pluriel-apres-genre-sorte-et-type)

  **Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 14, Needs Improvement: 4)
- [How to distinguish “à cette heure” from “à sept heures”?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6497/how-to-distinguish-a-cette-heure-from-a-sept-heures)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 14, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Comment traduire « associate's degree » en français ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6506/comment-traduire-associates-degree-en-francais)

  **Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Can I say: "Je l'aurais pensé!"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6458/can-i-say-je-laurais-pense)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 11, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Étendue géographique de l'expression « être de piquet » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6532/etendue-geographique-de-lexpression-etre-de-piquet)

  **Net Score: 10** (Excellent: 11, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Différence entre « C'est le samedi qu'ils organisent » et « C'est le samedi où ils organisent »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/difference-entre-cest-le-samedi-quils-organisent-et-cest-le-samedi-ou-i)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Faut-il dire « matériel » ou « hardware » en Informatique ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6487/faut-il-dire-materiel-ou-hardware-en-informatique)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 13, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Concise Québécois-appropriate phrase for "In English, please?"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6634/concise-quebecois-appropriate-phrase-for-in-english-please)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 12, Needs Improvement: 2)